# For Fitting in All Screen

Tags: html, css

I Had Made a Website it is Complete But it does not fits all displays Like on Mobile Phones So is there any code for html or css that it should automatically fits all types of screen.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is called "[responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)" and has to do with how to put together a site such that it conforms to the device's view. I don't believe there is anything that takes an existing site and makes it responsive.

There are frameworks for making this easier which you can find by searching for "[responsive framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=Responsive%20frameworks)".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't hear that something like this exists. So I think you will need to change it by yourself.

Don't know how you created your website but you have a lot of frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation, Material.

If you only need grid I would recommend you a [Gridism.](http://cobyism.com/gridism/)